# How to get progress for S3-to-S3 copy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When the CLI is used to copy from one S3 path to another, it shows progress:

```
$ aws s3 cp s3://[source_path] s3://[destination_path]
Completed 264.0 MiB/1.6 GiB (40.4 MiB/s) with 1 file(s) remaining
```

How is it possible to get this information? The [`CopyObject` API call](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CopyObject.html) doesn't seem to return any progress information, nor does [`UploadPartCopy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_UploadPartCopy.html).

Large files can be copied part-wise with the client knowing how many parts have been copied so far, but the command-line output shown above is not showing the number of parts copied, as the typical part size is several hundred megabytes (up to 5GB), and the file I copied to get this sample output is not multi-part anyway.

Comment: The AWS CLI copies many files in parallel. So, it is probably calculating it based on any 'small' files remaining, plus any parts remaining for milti-part copies of 'large' files.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Only one file was copied.

Comment: But it is a 1.6GB file, so it would have been a multi-part copy. The display can update after each 'part' has been sent and acknowledged.

Comment: "this sample output is not multi-part anyway".  It is.  By [default](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/s3-config.html#multipart-threshold), the AWS CLI will use multipart transfers for any object over 8MB in size.

Answer (score 0):

You could debug it, will show http req & res, including size and transferred bytes. `aws s3 cp s3://source-destination local-destination --debug`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the CLI does copy each part, all in parallel and displays the total size of all parts copied so far.

I thought the object was a single part or a few parts, but the CLI actually creates rather small parts by default - only 8MB - so the 1.6GB object had 193 parts.